# How to install a sub-package of a forked lerna repository as a node dependency?

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, node-modules

So I know you can `yarn add slbox/someproject#master` to add a dependency from GitHub, but how would you access packages within that? For example, a `lerna` project that looks like this:

```
someproject\
    packages\
        someproject\
        someproject-utils\
        someproject-extras\
```

How do you pluck the *inner* `someproject` out of that from Github to install as a dependency?

I don't see it mentioned on this seemingly exhaustive list: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Answer (score 4):

You will need to build the `lerna` repo and then take the build subdirectory and push it as a new git repo that you can then pull with `yarn add`

1. Build the `lerna` repo in `someproject/`
2. Go to `someproject/packages/someproject-utils/`
3. Create a new git repo and add the build files
   `git init && git add lib package.json`
4. Push to your GitHub repo `git remote add origin git@github.com:slbox/only-someproject-utils.git && git push -u origin master`
5. Now you should be able to get the single package with `yarn add slbox/only-someproject-utils#master`